# Javascript : setInterval and ClearInterval on one click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have the numbers 1-6 quickly flash on the screen when a button is clicked, then stop and display the random generated number. If I put `clearInterval` into the function it just displays the random Number and doesn't display the flashes up numbers before hand.

HTML

```
<div id='dice'>
    <div id='number'>0</div>
</div>
<div id='button'>
    <button onclick='roll()'>Roll Dice</button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let rollButton = document.querySelector('button');
let diceNumber = document.getElementById ('number');

function roll(){
  diceSides = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  var i = 0;
  let shuffleDice = setTimeout(function(){
    diceNumber.innerHTML = diceSides[i++];
    if(diceNumber == diceSides.length){
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 500);

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    diceNumber.innerHTML = random;
}
```

Comment: Your first problem is that you're using `setTimeout` (which executes only once) when you appear to want `setInterval` (which executes repeatedly.

Comment: Well you can use `clearInterval` with `setTimeout`.  Only problem is, "clearInterval" only occurs in the title and the introductory text to your code.  So we have no idea how you were trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you
*hint*: you can use `i` as a counter variable OR use your approach (define an array with numbers and use index to find them and put them in `number` tag)

**HTML**:

```
<div id='dice'>
    <div id='number'>0</div>
</div>
<div id='button'>
    <button onclick='roll()'>Roll Dice</button>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
let rollButton = document.querySelector('button');
let diceNumber = document.getElementById ('number');

function roll(){
    diceSides = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var i = 6;
    let shuffleDice = setInterval(function(){
        diceNumber.innerHTML = i;
        if(i == 0){
            clearInterval(shuffleDice);
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            diceNumber.innerHTML = random;
        }
        i--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/BurnBin/pen/QORmpo)
[clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)
[setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
[setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the help !

Comment: @Swink You are very wellcome

Answer (score 0):

SetTimeout only executes once. Also your variable is changed by the interval! 
After its over, you have to clear the interval with clearInterval.

```js
let rollButton = document.querySelector('button');

let diceNumber = document.getElementById ('number');

function roll(){
  diceSides = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  var i = 0;
  var shuffleDice = setInterval(function(){
    diceNumber.innerHTML = diceSides[i++];
    //use i
    if(i == diceSides.length){
      i = 0;
      //clear
      clearInterval(shuffleDice);
      
      // moved because the interval will change it
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
      diceNumber.innerHTML = String(random);
    }
  }, 500);

}
```

```html
<div id = 'dice'>
      <div id = 'number'>0</div>
    </div>
    <div id = 'button'>
      <button onclick =  'roll()'>Roll Dice</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: This was perfect, thank you. I didn't put the clearinterval and the random number variables inside the set Interval function when I initially tried this

Comment: @Swink No Problem! If it answered your questions, Mind upvoting? Thanks!

Comment: I would, Stack won't let me upvote due to my rank just yet :/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
var diceNumber = document.getElementById ('number');
const diceSides = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function roll(){
    let arr = [...diceSides,diceSides[Math.floor(Math.random() * diceSides.length)]];
    cycle(diceNumber,arr,200);
}

function cycle(element,arr,delay) {
  element.innerText=arr.shift();
  if (arr.length > 0)
    setTimeout(cycle,delay,element,arr,delay);
}
```

Given that you know precisely the list you want to iterate through, and thus the fixed number of iterations you want to execute, this seems cleaner and more concise than `setInterval`, which you would have to explicitly stop when you reach the end of the list. I like `setInterval` for things that will run an indeterminate period of time (for instance, until stopped by a user action).

What this says is: "Take this list of numbers (the last one being the random one). Show the first one and remove it from the list. Then wait a while and do it again, until you're out of numbers."

A couple other fine points here:

- `innerText` rather than `innerHTML`, since you're just setting string content.
- You want to use your random number as a key against your array of die faces, not directly - used directly, you get [0-5], not [1-6].
- Use the length of your array, rather than hard-coding '6' - always avoid magic numbers when you can. By referring everything back to your constant array, changing the values on the faces of the die (or the number of them) becomes trivial; just change the array and everything else will still work.

Normally, there are stack-size concerns with recursive code. In this case, that wouldn't be a problem because of the small size of the array. But beyond that, the fact that the recursion is going through `setTimeout` means that each one is a seprate entry on the queue, and the prior isn't waiting for the next to complete before it can exit.